# jQuery sortable запрещает выделение текста в элементах.

Tags: jquery

Есть список UL, на него навешан jQuery sortable. Работает все отлично, но таким образом запрещается выделение текста.

Подскажите, где в jQuery sortable(а также, по-моему, в draggable) отключается выделение текста?

Answer (score 2):

И правильно делает, что запрещает. ;)

```
*.unselectable {
   -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
}
```

Вот эти четыре подстроки и ищите.

Comment: меня интересует где именно она это делает, как я знаю.

Comment: не правильно что делает, точнее не обязательно это делать. Я тяну блок за хендл, а то что внутри блока надо уметь выделять.